# How to enable HTTP Pipelining with Spray-Can

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-client, spray-can

I read on the [spray-can](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-can/http-client/host-level/#using-an-httphostconnector) docs that it supports HTTP Pipelining. But there is no method or example specified anywhere on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a config setting. See [this](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-can/configuration/) or [this](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf) doc for all available settings in Spay config.

This setting turns it on:

```
spray.can.host-connector.pipelining = off
```

And this one has to be > 1 to effectively enable it:

```
spray.can.server.pipelining-limit = 1
```

By default pipelining is off.

Relevant description of each setting:

> ```
> # The maximum number of requests that are accepted (and dispatched to
> # the application) on one single connection before the first request
> # has to be completed.
> # Incoming requests that would cause the pipelining limit to be exceeded
> # are not read from the connections socket so as to build up "back-pressure"
> # to the client via TCP flow control.
> # A setting of 1 disables HTTP pipelining, since only one request per
> # connection can be "open" (i.e. being processed by the application) at any
> # time. Set to higher values to enable HTTP pipelining.
> # Set to 'disabled' for completely disabling pipelining limits
> # (not recommended on public-facing servers due to risk of DoS attacks).
> # This value must be > 0 and <= 128.
> pipelining-limit = 1
>
> # If this setting is enabled, the `HttpHostConnector` pipelines requests
> # across connections, otherwise only one single request can be "open"
> # on a particular HTTP connection.
> pipelining = off
> ```